# Maven exporting pom.xml with jar plugin

Tags: maven, copy, export, pom.xml, maven-jar-plugin

I am adding  attribute in the jar plugin to specify the location of jar file. But at that location maven is not exporting pom.xml file which is used in generating the jar. Can you please tell me how to export the pom.xml too in the same location other then the copy plugin

Comment: Could you post your pom.xml?

Comment: Why do you need such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that only goal packaging will put the artifact in a local repository. But then for each artifact I need to do the install so that it will get in the files system repository with the pom file. Copying the pom file using resource plugin will not help.